# Control to select from a list and change order of selected items

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want to use a control I've seen many times before, but I don't know what it's called, so I don't know how to look for it.  The control would have two listboxes.  The box on the left would list available items.  The box on the right would list selected items.  Buttons between the two lists would allow the user to move all items from the available list to the selected list, to move one item from available to selected, to remove one item from the selected list and return it to the available list, and to remove all items from the selected list.  There would be two other buttons, typically located on the right side of the selected list, that would allow the user to move one of the selected items up or down in the list of selected items.  Where can I find that control?

**The question referenced as a duplicate to this is not a duplicate.**

The referenced question asks how to do this.  I know perfectly well how to develop this control, and it won't take that long for me to do.  It will definitely be worth the time it would take to do it.  But because many, many programs have this type of functionality, I figured that somebody somewhere had written this control already, and uploaded it someplace for the rest of us to use so we don't have to spend half a day writing our own.  The point of my question, and the reason that it is not a duplicate, is that I am not asking how to develop this control.  I am asking if anybody here can point me to such a control that has already been developed.

Comment: I was going to ask a further question, but I see the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no common control like this. You have to develop it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard Windows control that I am familiar with that offers this functionality out-of-the-box, however it would be pretty straightforward to implement your own `UserControl` which contains these components:

- Two `ListBox` controls, one anchored top-left-bottom, the other top-right-bottom.
- Two `Button` controls in between with left and right arrows, anchored top only
- `Button` controls underneath the lists to move items up and down.

Comment: Yes, it would be easy enough to do it myself, and probably worth doing, but I am hoping someone somewhere had already done it and put it up on the web someplace.